# Game sprite animation

Tags: java, animation

This code animates my main game sprite by increasing the animation frame. First I check if the character is moving, then I increase the animation counter until it reaches the desired speed, and then if so, I increase the animation frame.

How can I make it more elegant and optimised in terms of speed?

```
       if (moving){
        anispeed++;
        if (anispeed==animaxspeed){
            anispeed=0;
            animationframe++;
            if (animationframe==3) animationframe=0;
        }
```

Comment: quick question, why do you need to reset the anispeed when increasing the animationframe by one? I don't understand why you do this... Your posted code also misses the closing brace. !!

Comment: Anispeed is used as a counter, when it hits animaxspeed then we change the animation to the next frame. Otherwise the animation is as fast as the computer can go.

Answer (score 7):

Two small comments:

**Naming:**
The convention for variable names in Java is `camelCase`. Your `animationframe` should instead be `animationFrame` when going by that rule. Similar for your `animaxspeed`. You don't have to save characters in your code, write it out: `animationMaxSpeed`.
`anispeed` can also be written out: `animationSpeed`. This should make your code even more clear than it is ;)

**Braces:**
It's also convention to place all if-blocks in braces, disregarding whether they have to, or not. This is to decrease the possibility of bugs when changing such blocks and forgetting braces.

```
if (animationFrame == 3) {
    animationFrame = 0;
}
```

Also the Java-Coding-Standard is 4 spaces indentation. It might be, that the markup for SE broke yours, but either way, your first if-statement is too far in.